# CSS files doesn't download in JSP page

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple html page. But css files doesn't download in the page. I have an error 404 when I try show image in `<style>` tags in the page. Nothing works.

[Catalog structure here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNrS.png)

home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="../../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        /*h2{*/
            /*color: red;*/
        /*}*/
        body {
            background: url(../../assets/img/javarush.jpg);

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="home">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
</div>
<button class="bg-primary btn-primary btn-lg">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.home {
    background-image: url('/assets/img/javarush.jpg');
    background-size: cover;

}
h2{
    color: #2b542c;
}
```

**UPDATE**: works only so

```
<style>
        <%@include file="/assets/css/style.css"%>
</style>
```

but image not found

**UPDATE 2**: in `dispatcherServlet` write     `<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>` and in .jsp write

```
<link href="<c:url value="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<c:url value="/assets/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it works great with image.

Comment: you can refer to the image from css file as  background-image: url('img/javarush.jpg');

Comment: It doesn't matter because html doesn't download style.css

Comment: when I refer `background-image: url('img/javarush.jpg');` IDE shows an error`

Answer (score 0):

The way to add css file:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

Other info:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and continues from there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory back and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories back and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first
  subdirectory and keep moving forward

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/style.css">`
doesn't work

Comment: why are you adding `../` twice?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">` doesn't work. Error 404

Comment: where is your css file located, is it in the root folder?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNrS.png

Comment: do this `href="/assets/css/style.css"`

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">` doesn't work

Comment: how about: href="assets/css/style.css" not starting with /

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong, but when I tried on my project this last one worked, which was actually relative to the index.html. When I moved the index file inside another folder, I had to go back with `../`, so you might even need to go 3 directories back...

Comment: well if moving a certain amount of directories back fails, you could use an absolute path, `http://my.site/pathtocss/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

```
.home {
    background-image: url('../img/javarush.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Changed, but still doesn't work

Comment: The path to get the css file seems correct since you need to jump out of pages and web-inf.

If you put your css inline does it load the image ?

Comment: no. `body {
            background: url(../../assets/img/javarush.jpg);

        }` doesn't load

Comment: Alright i've never used java to do web but it seems your file needs some context 

https://coderanch.com/t/628525/Servlets/java/CSS-stylesheet-work-JSP-files

    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".